# Are HYDRA's weapons related to Iron Man's repulsors?

Tags: avengers, technology, captain-america, iron-man, marvel

Speaking from the recent Marvel movies... I just watched *Captain America* last night (only missing the Hulk's individual movie now). I noticed that the HYDRA weapons made the same little "whine" before they fire, just like the hand repulsors built into the Iron Man suits.

Are the two technologies related at all, in the history of *The Avengers* universe or is there some other in-universe explanation cued by the use of the same sound? Maybe Tony Stark's designs were influenced by prior HYDRA work? Or was this more likely just the sound designer happened to like that sound effect and wanted to re-use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no definitive facts so far, however there are a couple of implied connections to the Arc Reactor.

- Following the [cinematic universe timeline](http://collider.com/wp-content/uploads/avengers-timeline.jpg), Howard Stark began developing the Arc Reactor some time after he found the Tesseract while trying to find Steve Rogers.
- During the battle with Iron Monger, the Arc Reactor shoots a column of light into the sky, similar to the Tesseract.
- They both share a similar power-up sound effect.
- It could also possibly explain how Mjolnir actually enhanced the Iron Man armor rather than damage it.

So Hydra's weapons may be related to Iron Man's Repulsors by way of their power source, rather than the weapon itself.

Comment: Was the flying car using repulsors or anti-gravity? Comments on this questions seem to suggest it was AG. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/why-is-tony-stark-in-the-iron-man-suit-unaffected-by-g-forces-inertia-and-blunt

Comment: @Xantec At the start of *Iron Man 1*, repulsor technology is presented as a new development in Stark weaponry, so I don't think that was repulsor tech.

Comment: @Keen I think you might be right. I just wrote it mostly from memory, I think it was an assumption I made while watching.Howard Stark called it “gravitic reversion technology” for anyone interested.

Comment: the real issue is, Mjolnir isn't related to the tesseract at all. The tesseract isn't asgardian tech, it is simply too advanced alien tech. There should be no reason for one to have any particular effect on the other. I would say that we know this for sure, but it was Loki that assured Thor that his hammer couldn't damage the portal and we never saw thor take a swing at it himself.