Has the physics of Magneto's powers been subjected to scrutiny in any movie or book?
Specifically, when he moves a massive object using his magnetic powers, he seems unaffected -- he attracts or repels the object but there is no reaction for the action as in Newton laws. Has it been stated in some canon that he can also control his own body's inertia?
Note that the question is not whether what Magneto does is possible -- it is probably less possible than many science fiction things, like visiting another star system seems to me to be more possible than a human being able to manipulate magnetic fields.
My question wasn't about how his powers might be possible, but rather if some canon explores how someone with normal mass can move very massive metal objects without those same objects causing him to move. If some movie or book even made an attempt to explain how he could apparently violate every action having a reaction.
If indeed he does himself act as sort of a magnet but instead manipulates the Earth's magnetic field is offered as the explanation in any work about him, that would answer my question.

My understanding is that he manipulates magnetic fields, including the Earth's. Thus the reaction would be against the Earth and not his physical form.

We're talking about a man who can wave his hand and move metal because his genes are weird, whose biggest enemy is a person who can hear your thoughts from the other side of the planet. He's already so magical that expecting him to respect Isaac Newton seems churlish (and borderline off-topic as a real-world science question).

I think it's pretty much the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/why-is-tony-stark-in-the-iron-man-suit-unaffected-by-g-forces-inertia-and-blunt
